# NSTextField updated randomly through delegate in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, random, delegates, nstextfield

I have a very strange behavior on a NSTextField.

I update the value of the NSTextField through a delegate. Sometimes it gets updated and sometimes not. I issued a print statement before to ensure that I have the correct value. What the print statement shows and what is being displayed on the NSTextField is different.

Any idea what could be the root cause ?

```
import Cocoa

var mtserialport = MTSerialHandler()


class ManualViewController: NSViewController, MTSerialHandlerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var txtStatus       : NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtQueue        : NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        init_ctrl()

        // Delegates
        mtserialport.delegate = self
    }

    func init_ctrl() {
        self.txtQueue.stringValue  = "0"
    }

    // This is the function called from a delegate
    // mt_serialport delegate
    // print shows updateQueue:0 or 1, textQueue would stay to a previous value. i.e:3
    func updateQueue(qu: UInt) {
        print("updateQueue:" + String(qu))
        self.txtQueue.stringValue = String(qu)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the value `3` which you say it is previous? You are printing the `txtQueue` value before setting a new value, so try to print it after setting the value and check.

Comment: Make sure you update the textfield on the main thread. Updating it from a background queue can lead to some weird behaviors

Comment: everything is being run on the main thread. The value 3 is set in a different class (mtserialport) and is being propagated to the updateQueue function through a delegate. The value printed is correct but the txtQueue value displayed is not